# SSL certificate error while creating a package for Octopus

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy

I want to create an online build definition VSTS (now Azure-DevOps) and then push the package to Octopus. But while executing the Package task I get the following error:

> Error: unable to get local issuer certificate Failed to execute `octo pack` command. unable to get local issuer certificate

Can anyone provide me with some insights on this?

Comment: How did you package and publish to Octopus? Have you tried the extension [Octopus Deploy Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octopusdeploy.octopus-deploy-build-release-tasks)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is solved. Turns out, firstly I had to change the version of nuget package and make some modifications regarding the source path in my build server, and therefore it was facing problem while fetching the local issuer certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways could be to try changing/upgrading the nuget package version. Also verify the Source path you are providing of your Build server, it should be at the location where website data is stored after build.